# SequelizeDatabaseError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have web project (nodejs,reactjs) 2 years live. For database it is used MySQL and sequelize library for nodejs. suddenly a problem arose with sequelize on tables which have column dataType.JSON. "Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined" . Quite strangely, we didn't do any package updates.

https://screenrec.com/share/2hCjuOalwG

Comment: please don't post images of code or error messages see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Started acting up for us starting today as well. Current RCA is pointing towards a raw query being used `sequelize.query('SELECT ... ')`  instead of the intended way using models. I believe this is where Sequelize is having a problem (for us anyway).

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't change anything in the database check the connection from the nodejs because i think you cannot reach the database. so there is something in the connection or the url of mysql server

Comment: for other tables everything works, just tables which has column json type. connection is working

Comment: try to change the field type to string and run it will work ??